# Как сделать прозрачность(Opacity) только Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть Grid, в котором есть эелементы. Как мне сделать `Grid` прозрачным, а элементы, нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас это выглядит так.

Код XAML

```
 <Grid Height="250" Width="280" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Gray" Opacity="0.5">
                <Button Content="Acscess" Width="90" Height="27" x:Name="Autorization" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,45,0,0" />
                <Button Content="Go by Guest" Width="76" x:Name="Guest" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,130,0,0"/>
                <TextBox Text="TextBox" Height="34" Width="171" Margin="0,0,0,100" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <PasswordBox Width="136" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,29"/>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: `Background="Gray"` - поддерживает ARGB, где A - прозрачность, достаточно в студии задать цвету эту саму прозрачность. Другой вариант, сделать некую заднюю подложку, которая будет на всю сетку и уже ей задавать цвет и прозрачность.

Comment: <Grid.Background>
  <SolidColorBrush Color="Grey" Opacity="0.5"/>. 
  </Grid.Background>. Если прозрачность вставлять непосредственно в свойствах грида, то она наследуется и на потомков

Comment: @Ivan `Background="#99999980"` вы не читали комментарий выше, видимо.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid Background="#80ABABAB" ...
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]